# replaceAll function doesn't work in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js v14.18.1 and here is what I got (after shrinking my code down to a single line):

```
    console.log("anything".replaceAll("a","a"));
                           ^
TypeError: "anything".replaceAll is not a function
```

Though it's working in a developer.mozilla.org snippet box. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

[`String#replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) only works on version Node version 15.0.0 and above, [according to Node Green](https://node.green/#ES2021-features--String-prototype-replaceAll).

Answer (score 2):

Replace all is implemented after node 15.0.0.

You can use the following to replace all

```
"anything".replace(/a/g, "b");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on node.js 15.0.0 or higher. So, you need to update your node version or install another version (15+) and switch it by nvm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is a simple copy of an existing answer. Be sure, when you answer to an old questions, with upvoted answer, that your answer gives new information that was not provided before.